# Swift XCTest and asserts

Tags: swift

I'm using Swift2.

Assume I have a function:

```
func divide(x x:Int, y:Int) -> Double? {
    assert(y != 0)

    if (y == 0) {
        return nil
    } else {
        return (Double(x)/Double(y))
    }
}
```

For debugging purposes I'd like use assert, so I can see when passes y = 0 in this function.

I'd like to also have a workaround in production (I don't want to crash, just notify user), that he cannot divide by 0. I have a test:

```
let res = divide(5, 0)
XCTAssert(res == nil)
```

But instead of finishing the test I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on assert in divide function.

Can I disable asserts somehow for tests?

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to add a default parameter to the function that could be used to bypass the assert:

```
func divide(x x:Int, y:Int, safe:Bool=true) -> Double? {
    if safe {
        assert(y != 0)
    }

    if (y == 0) {
        return nil
    } else {
        return (Double(x)/Double(y))
    }
}
```

In your app you would continue to call it with the  `x` and `y` parameters

```
divide(5, 0)
```

and you would get an assert.

In your test you would call it with the `safe` parameter as `false` which would bypass the assert and allow you to use `XCTAssert` on the result:

```
let res = divide(5, 0, false)
XCTAssert(res == nil)
```